# How do I get MVCSiteMap to include all my custom generated pages in the sitemap.xml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I have combed through the documentation but I could not find what I am looking for. It is possible what I am looking for is not possible, this is new territory to me.

I am using [MVCSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) for the first time. I need to make sure that search engines can crawl a list of dynamically created pages in my asp.net mvc site.

The view is created based off of two parameter: title and id. The url is spits out is defined in a custom route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "JobResults",                                           // Route name
      "JobSearch/{title}-{id}",                            // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "JobSearch", action = "Job" },  // Parameter defaults
        new[] { "MyApp.Web.Controllers" }
        );
```

So when I click on a link it will take me to: localhost:43736/JobSearch/chief-talent-officer-1710

I set up the sitemap plugin and messed with the .sitemap file so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="HiringSolutions" controller="Home" action="HiringSolutions"/>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Privacy Policy" controller="Home" action="Privacy"/>
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Terms" controller="Home" action="Terms" />
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Search" controller="JobSearch" action="Index"  changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal">
          <mvcSiteMapNode title="Job" controller="JobSearch" action="Job" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="High" route="JobResults"/>
        </mvcSiteMapNode>
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

To see what it comes up with I called this on my index page: `@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false, true, true)`. It renders out this:

- Home
- About
- HiringSolutions
- Privacy Policy
- Terms
- Search

  - Job

How can I get it to do this dynamically?:

- Home
- About
- HiringSolutions
- Privacy Policy
- Terms
- Search

  - Job

    - /JobSearch/chief-talent-officer-1710
    - /JobSearch/another-one-1234
    - /JobSearch/another-one-1235
    - /JobSearch/another-one-1236
    - /JobSearch/another-one-1237

And once I have that (if possible), does this create a sitemap.xml file in the root of my site, or do I need to do something to make that reachable by bots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [DynamicNodeProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) sound like what you're looking for? The sample code shows how to build a set of nodes from a database query.

```
public class StoreDetailsDynamicNodeProvider 
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
{ 
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node) 
    {
        using (var storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities())
        {
            // Create a node for each album 
            foreach (var album in storeDB.Albums.Include("Genre")) 
            { 
                DynamicNode dynamicNode = new DynamicNode(); 
                dynamicNode.Title = album.Title; 
                dynamicNode.ParentKey = "Genre_" + album.Genre.Name; 
                dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("id", album.AlbumId);

                yield return dynamicNode;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to create a manual page which lists all Jobs in your database, since the sitemap-provider (or Google) can't possibly know what to put as arguments to the Job- or Search-page.

Either that or create a script which generates the `sitemap.xml` for you. In either case this is a job *you* have to do, because only you know the structure of your data.

Comment: Actually, no that is exactly what MvcSiteMapProvider does. Using IDynamicNodeProvider (or ISiteMapNodeProvider), you can specify custom route values so all of the URLs driven from dynamic data are included in sitemap.xml. The only extra thing that is needed is to configure the routes in MVC to get the URLs that are desired.